# How to Intervene the google play store app installation process?

Tags: android, google-play, reverse-engineering, android-install-apk

I am developing a service which performs some security check on an apk file. I want to plug-in this service into google play store installation process, So that when the apk download is complete instead of installation, apk is first passed to the service, the service performs the security check and then installation of apk proceeds. Is there any way I could Intervene the google play store app installation process and achieve this ?

one way i can think of is, let the play store install the app, get the name of the installed package through `android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED` receiver, access the apk installed in /data/app with `PackageManager` and `PackageInfo`, pass it to the service and then reinstall analysed apk with `PackageInstaller`. Is there any better way to achieve this?

Any help in this direction will be highly appreciated. thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you planning on building your own custom ROM that contains this modified version of the package installation process?

Comment: @CommonsWare No. I am trying to develop this entire process as an app which can be installed by any user without modifying underlying Android OS

Comment: I don't want to modify existing process just trying to plug-in my service between download and installation. rest stays as it is.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine that was possible and a normal app can interfere with the installation process from Play, and as you mention, change the downloaded APK to be a completely different one, not what the user thinks it is.

Don't you see a huge security risk here?

Comment: I agree with you on the security part. that's why I am exploring other ways also. Thanks for bringing this to my notice. any thoughts on other possible ways?